# how to download and extract and then delete tar.gz in php

Tags: php, github

I have a githhub repo that is a webapp that users download and host on a local webserver. Its written in php. Currently you have to manually download the zip/tar.gz files and replace the old ones. Is there a way to create an auto update function using php so when there is a new version on github it will offer the user a link to download and update the files or even if you have to click a link to check for updates and if there is an update then it updates it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that Wordpress does something similar. When there is a new release, just click on the "update automatically" button and enter your FTP/SFTP username, password and server and it downloads the newest release and installs it automatically.

However, you mentioned that users will have it installed "locally". Not everyone has an FTP server running on their local computer. In fact, I would say not many. And trying to get PHP to use its file manipulation functions would also be a nightmare due to permission errors.

Comment: Well, you could always code something to do it by FTP, but it wouldn't work for those who don't have FTP servers. If you would expect most people would, then yeah, I would say go for it. It shouldn't be too hard to code. If not, then it's probably not worth the hassle.